# How do I lower my driver rating in Gran Turismo Sport?

Tags: gran-turismo-sport

I am going for the two gold trophies in this game (65 pole positions and 91 wins). So far I have been racing as good as I can and I managed to do around 20 pole positions and 10 wins. This brought me to driver rating B and sportsmanship rating B.

I find that at this level, winning and doing pole positions is already starting to get very difficult, especially with a DS4. In the last 20 races, I did 1 pole position and 0 wins, so I am trying to lower my driver rating so I can get some easier wins (don’t judge me, trophies are still part of the game :P )

Therefore I have come last position on purpose in the last 15 races but my driver rating is the same. My sportsmanship rating increased because I was still racing clean, so I also tried driving dirtier (cutting corners etc) and still getting last position, and the max I have achieved is driver rating high C and sportsmanship rating C.

So, what do I have to do exactly to go back to driver rating D or E? Do I have to just continue losing races a million times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter how much you lose and what you do to your sportsmanship ranking.

There are other things that go first:

- driver rating of your opponents

  - if you get beaten by people ranked worse, that's what you want to achieve, because that will have an impact
  - getting beaten by people ranked equally or higher will have a lower impact on your score
- difference between your quali position and your finish (here losing would finally matter, but still depending on who you raced against)
- Lowering your sportsmanship will likely put you in a butchery, but not lower your driver rating.. if you want to race with hostile opponents you can keep up, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Because you are normally matched vs opponents at your same level then, I can see this taking a while :D

Comment: @user1301428 although they try to do that the sportsmanship also matters a lot. Maybe you should really try to de-rank your SR, since newbies start at rank E..?